# Red5 video recorder is not smooth in centos server

Tags: red5

I have used the RED5 1.0 RC1 version, and at the time of video recording, sometime it records and sometimes it does not. What is the issue that i cannot find, can anybody helps.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This article](http://hdfvr.com/documentation#part11) covers recording issues with each Red5 version.
This [patched Red5 1.0.2](http://nusofthq.com/blog/recording-high-quality-hd-video-over-slow-connections-with-red5-is-now-possible/) fixes the recording issues.

Answer (score 0):

use red5 version 0.8, instead of the 1.0RC1, 0.8 is better for recordings.

Comment: Red5 0.8 does not account for Flash Player's prioritisation of audio packets over video packets when streaming/recording over slow connections. Red5 1.0RC1 introduces such a mechanism but my results with it are mixed.